# Django: What's the standard way to use a view just to process a form?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

A user is viewing another user's profile at `profile/userB/`, and clicks the Add Friend button.

This submits a `POST` form containing both users to the `create` view in the `friends` app (`friends/create/`), which processes the data, creates a new `Friend` object and saves it in the database. A flash message is set as feedback, and the user finds themselves back on at `profile/userB/`.

The user never sees `friend/create/`.

This feels really obvious, and I did this regularly with CakePHP, but I'm having trouble picturing this in Django. I'm trying to keep a forms.py separate, with templates surrounding forms separate as well (e.g. the 'Add Friend' template may be included in various locations, including the form and submitting as above). I think that's the right way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: So you just want to redirect back to `profile/userB/` after processing the form?

Comment: In this example, yes, but it would also need to redirect back to anywhere else the form is used, not just profile. I'm really looking for the pattern or standard way of doing this I can use anywhere, as I haven't seen this covered in any tutorial, and it was something cakephp introduced early on

Comment: I'm not sure what does your `form` look like, but since "Add Friend" is merely a button, you could instead use ajax. In this case, your page is not even refreshed, you can still hit the url `friend/create/` to create friendship and fetch response.

Comment: If you want it to be portable, use django template tag to wrap the button + the javascript code, then you can use it everywhere in your project. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags

Comment: Or you could submit the current url with the form. Then, after the `Friend` object/relationship is created, `HttpResponseRedirect` back to that url.

Comment: A friend will build a better front-end long term and I'm inexperienced with js and ajax. I just need something presentable. How would I pass the current URL within the form? Are there any examples I could use? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you don't even need a form and there's no need to submit `POST`. Instead of defining your url as `friend/create/`, use something like this:

```
url(r'^create-friendship/(?P<user_id>\d+)/$', 'create_friendship', name='create-friendship'),
```

Then you define your `Add Friend` as a link(but you should make it like a button for user experience), roughly like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'app:create-friendship' userB.id %}?from={{ request.path|urlencode }}">Add friend</a>
```

Notice that I added a `GET` parameter `from` at the end of the link, that's the current url you pass to the view method. Then in your create view:

```
def create_friendship(user_id):
    # logic to build your friendship relationship between user_id and request.user
    if request.GET.get('from'):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.GET.get('from'))
    else:
        # return to some other urls
```

There's no "built-in" way to do this in django, but once you understand the framework better, it should become obvious.

ps: In order to access `request` variable in django template, you have to enable a template processor, add following to your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSOR in settings:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
  # ...
  'django.core.context_processors.request',
  # ...
)
```

Comment: Can I pass a context variable to the destination view in the redirect?

Comment: I think I can use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect